# EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000 only in my computer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

so as I wrote in the title I get that my 5000 port is in use although it is not , I’m on a Mac OS and I tried to kill the port as would normally do.

```
npx kill-port 5000
```

also change the port in my node app and yet its the same , I also tried

```
sudo lsof -i :5000

sudo killall -9 node
```

nothing seems to work , and the most strange part for me was that it did work completely fine on another computer, windows OS if it matters.

this is the full error message, as you can see the react runs successfully but the node claim that the port is in use.

```
[0] events.js:292
[0]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[0]       ^
[0] 
[0] Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
[0]     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
[0]     at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
[0]     at Server.listen (net.js:1452:7)
[0]     at Function.listen (/Users/hamudi/Documents/Learning/Mini Projects/devMeet/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hamudi/Documents/Learning/Mini Projects/devMeet/server.js:45:5)
[0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
[0]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
[0]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
[0]     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[0] Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
[0]     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
[0]   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
[0]   errno: -48,
[0]   syscall: 'listen',
[0]   address: '::',
[0]   port: 5000
[0] }
[0] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://10.0.0.5/
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /Users/hamudi/Documents/Learning/Mini Projects/devMeet/client/public
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
[1] Starting the development server...
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try restarting your computer?

Comment: Yes of course as I though it might be something from the Mac and I still do but not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh my god , after a few days i'v managed to solve this just now.
so let's make it simple:
if you are a Mac user and recently updated your OS to Monterey then you should know that **apple is using this port for airplay receiver**

```
there’s a new setting under System Preferences -> Sharing called Airplay Receiver.
```

toggle it off.

now of course you can change the port and I don't recommend to turn it off but just so you can check and understand that it is this that causing the problems, when you turn it off it will work(at least it did for me) and then you can bring it back on and change your port in node.js

"Once this is done, you should find Port 5000 instantly freed up. It’s weird that Apple would pick such a commonly used port, especially for developers!"

I found this here :
https://utf9k.net/questions/macos-port-5000-monterey/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using *nix, you can use `netstat -ap | grep <portnumber>` to see *specifically* what's using the process; it could potentially be another resource/service such as Docker.

Notably, `netstat` also works in Powershell (tested in Win 11), however no native support for `grep`, so you might just need to eyeball the list.

Comment: didn't work on my mac , netstate needs an argument

Comment: Did you pass the argument(s) `-ap`?

Comment: yes, but it's great know i've solved the issue and as I stated down below it was something from apple newest software update.